# Why does sendDelayed() increase time of sending in powers of 2?

Tags: omnet++

I am really new to Omnet++ and I don't understand what these values are. Why is the simulation time increasing in powers of 2?

[image]

This is the code for the message handler :

```
 void box::initialize() {
    if(strcmp("box", getName()) == 0) {
        packet1 *m = new packet1;
        m->setName("message");
        send(m, "out");
    }
}

void box::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    if(strcmp(msg->getName(), "message") == 0) {
        sendDelayed(msg,SIMTIME_DBL(simTime())+1,"out");
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the simulation time values be 0 and then 1 and then 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, that according to [OMNeT++ Simulation Library API](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cSimpleModule.html#aba0a65c43d5a34cc96f62507c8774838) the second argument of `sendDelayed()` is a delay, not an absolute time of sending. Moreover, `simTime()` returns the current simulation time. As a result, your code schedules the messages as follows:
in t = 0s - schedules at t + 0 + 1 = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1s
in t = 1s - schedules at t + t + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3s
in t = 3s - schedules at t + t + 1 = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7s
in t = 7s - schedules at t + t + 1 = 7 + 7 + 1 = 15s
....
where t is simulation time.

In order to apply one second delay, one should write:

```
sendDelayed(msg, 1.0, "out");
```